# C# Lambda - get distinct Id and append other field value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of Ids and Title as given below:

```
    List<Event> events= new List<Event>();

    events.Add(new Event(){ Id= "1001", Title= "abc" });
    events.Add(new Event(){ Id= "1002", Title= "xyz" });
    events.Add(new Event(){ Id= "1001", Title= "hij" });
    events.Add(new Event(){ Id= "1002", Title= "opq" });
    events.Add(new Event(){ Id= "1003", Title= "efg" });
```

Here, i want to get distinct **Ids** and **comma separated Title** against those Ids using `C# lambda expression`

Expected result:

```
[
    {Id: 1001,Title : "abc,hij"},
    {Id: 1002,Title : "xyz,opq"},
    {Id: 1003,Title : "efg"},
]
```

could you please let me know how can i achieve this using `C# Lambda expression`. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `String.Join`

```
var query = events.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(g => new Event 
     { 
         Id = g.Key, 
         Title = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Title)) 
     });
```

If you want a new list append `.ToList()`.